# Keeping connection alive on a urllib2.request() call

Tags: python, urllib2

Keeping the same format like this:

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.example.com', data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=4)
content = response.read()
```

Instead of using timeout=4, how can I use it with keep connection alive for as long as it takes?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a very long timeout:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=9999)
```

In addition you should look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), a much nicer lib than urllib2:

```
requests.get('http://www.example.com')
```

This by default hangs until the connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks. It's one of the great ways to get it done. If I don't use timeout, can I use something like: response = urllib2.urlopen(request, connection=keepalive)

Comment: I think `timeout=None` will do that. But really, use requests. urllib2 is really old school.

Comment: I'll look into requests and update later. Anyway, both timeouts work great with my old code. Save my day. Thanks a bunch